# jquery ck editor get current clicked id, so i will find parent div id

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

function load_web_page_content(user_website_informations_id,web_page_id) { 
               $.ajax({
                    url: "/AdminPanel/website/load_web_design_page",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{"user_website_informations_id":user_website_informations_id,"web_page_id":web_page_id},
                    success: function (e) { 
                      //  console.log(e);
                       // window.history.pushState("Website Sayfası", "Halid", "/Admin/website/index");
                            $(".panel-flat div.panel-body .card").html(e);
                          ck_load();
                     }
                    });
               function ck_load(){
                   var text_elements=$("div#text_editor");
                       text_elements.each(function(){ 
                                  var ck=  CKEDITOR.inline( this );
                                    ck.on( "instanceReady", function( ev ) {
                                     var editor = ev.editor;
                                     editor.setReadOnly( false );

```
                                  var data = ev.editor.getData();
                                  alert("Sending: " + data)
                             });
                      });                 
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question , i need to access parent div and parent section , so;

```
    text_elements.on( "click", function( ev )
                                {
                                    var section_id=$(this).closest("section").attr("id");  section_modify_alert(section_id);
                                     var div_id=$(this).closest("div").parent().attr("id");  section_modify_alert(div_id);

                                });
function div_modify_alert(div_id) {
              alert(div_id);
            }
            function section_modify_alert(section_id) {
              alert(section_id)
            }
```